# how to unit test this threaded code

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class that normally runs in a thread that processes data forever until another thread invokes stop() on it. The problem I have is that the unit test gets stuck in the main loop since the test is single threaded *and I want to keep it that way*. How can I unit test this without polluting the code? this class is part of a critical system and needs to be as simple and efficient as possible so I want to avoid unit testing hacks in the code

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable {

   boolean running;

   public void run() {
      //foo is injected from the outside
      foo.start();
      work();
      foo.end();
   }

   public void work() { 
      running = true;
      while(running) { //main loop
         bar.process(); //bar is injected from the outside
      }
   }

   public void stop() {
      running = false;
   }
}
```

Basically what I'm doing in the test is mocking out *foo* and *bar* and I call `run()` from the unit test, where later I verify in the *bar* mock whether `process` was actually called. I also verify that in the *foo* mock `start()` and `end()` got called. The problem is that because I really want to keep the test single threaded, the test thread gets stuck forever in the `while(running)` loop.

Some things I have tried and don't like

- add some VM property to trigger a break at the end of the iteration of the main loop. The problem with this is that as mentioned, this code is very critical and I want to keep the code clear of unit-testing clutter. I don't want production code evaluating in every iteration some VM property that I only use at development time
- use the *bar* mock to invoke `stop()` on its call of process(). Mockito doesn't like the fact that I call another class' method and throws an exception
- externalize the control of the mainloop. so instead of checking a boolean in the while, I call a method that returns whether to continue or not. And this loop-control object can be injected from the outside, that way in the unit test i can make the control method return true and then false to get a single iteration out of the loop. This complexifies the code quite a bit and makes it unnatural and harder to read plus it only would make any sense in a unit test context

Are there any other suggestions or common patterns to test Runnables, or maybe a better way to write my code so that testing it is easier?

Comment: To write a test you need to know the specification. The tests check the that the code conforms to the specification.  You have not told ys the specification,  so *nobody* can tell you how to test your code.

Comment: Note that if you call stop from a different thread, there is no guarantee that the change in running will be seen. You have to declare it volatile, make access to the variable synchronized OR make it an AtomicBoolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface for the class of `bar` that only contains the method `process`. Your `MyClass` seems generic enough so that this would be OK. Then, instead of mocking `bar`, create your own implementation dummy (or mock, whatever you like to call it). This will then call the stop method and your `process` method is only called once. You can check whether `BarMock.process` was called with an assertion using its `isCalled` method. Also, I would suggest an `isRunning` method for your `MyClass` so that you can check whether it was stopped.

```
public interface Processable {
    public void process();
}

public class BarMock implements Processable {
    private MyClass clazz;
    private boolean called;

    public BarMock(MyClass clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        called = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        // you can assertTrue(clazz.isRunning()) here, if required
        called = true;
        clazz.stop();
    }

    public boolean isCalled() {
        return called;
    }
}

public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    boolean running;

    public void run() {
        // foo is injected from the outside
        foo.start();
        work();
        foo.end();
    }

    public void work() {
        running = true;
        while (running) { // main loop
            bar.process(); // bar is injected from the outside
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
}
```

I think this method has three advantages over the one suggested by William F. Jameson, but also disadvantages:

Advantages:

- You can test whether your `process` method was actually called
- You don't have to add code that you never use during the actual program run
- You can test whether the `stop` method really stops

Disadvantages:

- You have to introduce an interface
- Need to test BarMock class, too

That said, I'd still prefer introducting the interface, since it doesn't pollute your code too much and therefore is a small price to pay.

Comment: ah, this was dead simple. My bar was already an interface and I tried to do what you suggested using mockito (as mentioned in point #2 of my OP) but i missed completely creating my own mock. thank you

Comment: @Hilikus: yes, i can relate to that. I'm sometimes so into using a technology that I forget the simple things :)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest making a change which would both make your code more by-the-book *and* allow breaking out in a single thread:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && running) {
     bar.process();
  }
```

You can call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` before you run this code; the thread's `interrupted` flag will be set and the method `isInterrupted()` will return true.

This is more by-the-book because it makes your main loop participate in  Java's interruption mechanism.

Comment: i just tried this and it doesn't work as described. If you call interrupt() before the call to run(), like you suggest, the while loop doesn't even run once since the first time already isInterrupted returns true. A possible solution is to use a do-while loop instead

Comment: Also, in my real code, invoking interrupt on the thread is not the same as calling stop, which might be the case for others as well. calling stop is a clean exit where foo.end() would be called, whereas interrupting the thread makes end() not be called. Still +1, a good solution to the code i gave here

Comment: I am surprised that `end()` is not called because it follows after `work()`, and `work()` completes normally in both cases (whether `stop()` or `interrupt()` was called). The only real difference is that `interrupt()` is a global interruption mechanism and will cause any interruptible blocking call to throw `InterruptedException`, potentially interrupting the workflow earlier than with `stop()`. This is many times a *good* thing because a blocking call may otherwise take a very long time.

Comment: BTW you could have kept `while (running)`, but added an `if (...isInterrupted()) break;` to the end of the `while` body to ensure `process()` being called at least once, while still keeping the *interruptible* property of the loop.

Comment: your surprise comes from the oversimplification of the code I pasted here. I was saying that in my actual code, end() would not be called because the contract says that end() gets called only if the thread ended cleanly. And you are right about the if at the end

Comment: But that's what I was saying, the `interrupted` flag should also have caused a clean end. What exactly do you use to detect that it wasn't clean? Do you explicitly check the `running` flag?